# Making Sign up form using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I want that whenever the new user makes a sign up. C# code should check the value in database table whether the user with the same name exists or not . i am using sql-server for storing data and procedures to insert data. i am using a unique constraint in table and if the user with same name exists it should give a error message on the screen.

Procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SigningIn]
@UserName nvarchar(90),
@Password nvarchar(90)
 AS

insert into Signin(UserName,UserPassword) values
                     (@UserName,@Password)
RETURN
```

C# code

```
    if(user name doesn't exists)
        var command = new SqlCommand("SigningIn", connection)
        {
            CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        };
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", UserNameBox.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", PasswordBox.Text);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connection.Close();
    }
    else
    {
        UserExists.Text = "User Already Exists";
    }
```

Asp code

```
 <asp:Label CssClass="col-sm-6 control-label " ID="UserName" runat="server"  Text="User name"></asp:Label>
  <div class="col-sm-6 ">
      <asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Pick a user name"   ID="UserNameBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator CssClass="validators" ID="UserValidator" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Field is Required" ForeColor="#FF3300" ControlToValidate="UserNameBox" SetFocusOnError="True" ClientIDMode="Static" Display="Dynamic" ViewStateMode="Enabled"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
   </div></div></div>
             <div class="form-horizontal ">
            <div class="form-group ">

  <asp:Label CssClass="col-sm-6 control-label " ID="Password" runat="server" Text="Password"></asp:Label>
  <div class="col-sm-6 ">
   <asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Enter password" ID="PasswordBox" runat="server" TextMode="Password" ></asp:TextBox>
      <asp:RequiredFieldValidator CssClass="validators" ID="passwordValidator" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Field is Required" ForeColor="#FF3300" ControlToValidate="PasswordBox" SetFocusOnError="True" ClientIDMode="Static" Display="Dynamic" ViewStateMode="Enabled">                   </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

</div></div></div>
              <div class="form-horizontal ">
            <div class="form-group ">


    <asp:Label CssClass="col-sm-6 control-label " ID="ConfirmLabel" runat="server" Text="Confirm Password"></asp:Label>
    <div class="col-sm-6 ">
      <asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Confirm Password" TextMode="Password"  ID="ConfirmBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> <asp:Label ID="UserExists" CssClass="validators" runat="server" Text="" ></asp:Label>
       <asp:RequiredFieldValidator CssClass="validators" ID="confirmValidator" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Field is required" ControlToValidate="ConfirmBox" SetFocusOnError="True" Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
      <asp:CompareValidator ID="comparePassword" CssClass="validators" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Password doesn't match" SetFocusOnError="True" ControlToCompare="PasswordBox" ControlToValidate="ConfirmBox" ForeColor="#FF3300"></asp:CompareValidator>
```

Comment: SO is not a code writing service [See this guide on how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). If there is something in particular you're stuck on, then ask about that.

Comment: http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually set the condition directly from your procedure, which is to insert only when it doesn't exist, like so:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SigningIn]
@UserName nvarchar(90),
@Password nvarchar(90)
 AS
BEGIN
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Signin WHERE UserName = @UserName)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO Signin(UserName,UserPassword) VALUES(@UserName,@Password);
END
END
```

Or to continue with C# code:

```
using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connString)){
connection.Open();
bool userNameExists = false;

var command = 
new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Signin WHERE UserName = @UserName", connection);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName",UserNameBox.Text.Trim();
userNameExists = (int)command.ExecuteScalar() > 0;

//if exists
if(userNameExists) {
UserExists.Text = "User Already Exists";
}else{
command = new SqlCommand("SigningIn", connection);
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", UserNameBox.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", PasswordBox.Text);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
connection.Close();
}
```

Comment: Actually i was using the direct value of text box in query to make a check operation. like userName.text

Comment: what is **executeScalar** method. I know only about   ExecuteNonQuery and ExecuteReader

Comment: executing scalar value means getting only a single or a set of values.  This is useful if you don't need to get the all the values for the entire row

Comment: `(int)command.ExecuteScalar() > 0` why you have used greater than zero

Comment: because the Sql Command (SELECT COUNT(*)) checks if there is at least one email address found.

You may also use SELECT UserName FROM Signin but then when you query ExecuteScalar, you check for the UserName that's found and not the count.